# Describe/define the area of a scalar field that can be reached by local search

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology, publishing

Lets assume I have a [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) (which is a [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)), which describes a density. For my publication I want to properly define a certain area in this scalar field. The idea is this: Lets start with any point in the space and apply a [local search optimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) (e.g. [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing)) to the point until I converge. The area I am interested in is the set of all points from which I can start the local search method and still converge to the same point in space.

I thought about using the vector field, which is the derivative of the scalar field, in the definition and use some notion of "reachablility". But I am not quite sure on how express this concise. Maybe the derivative is not required to be mentioned. I thought about using some sort of sense of "density-connectedness", where the vectors connect all the points with each other that can be reached, following the vectors - but this is obviously not yet very polished.

Btw: [Mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) would be an implementation of a local search (which is not hill climbing) if the scalar field is constructed using a kernel density estimation.

---

My goal is to define a cluster for mean shift and similar methods such that it is algorithm independent. If possible even not in Euclidean but in general metric space. Currently my definition is:

> Given an Euclidean space for which points a density based on given data objects, which are elements of the Euclidean space, can be calculated.
>   Then a cluster mode is a local maxima of the respective density function.
>   Then the cluster mode is a sink for the conservative vector field of the density function (the vector field that is made up from the gradients of the density function at the points in the Euclidean space).
>   Then, a cluster is a connected component (maximal connected subset) of the Euclidean space, which elements are in the same basin of attraction for the same cluster mode.

Comment: This is called the "basin of attraction."  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Basins_of_attraction)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Thanks, I am reading into it. Could you elaborate in an answer? As far as I can see the article does not refer any vector field or scalar field. I understand what the intuition is that you are getting at, but my scalar field is not exactly a differential equation and I am not sure how the scalar field translates to "dynamical systems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term that you are looking for is a [basin of attraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BasinofAttraction.html).

#### Dynamical Systems

In broad terms, a dynamical system is a family of functions $\{f_t\}$, where the index or parameter $t$ can be taken to be either the integers or the reals.  This family of functions must satisfy the property that
$$ f_s \circ f_t = f_{s+t} $$
for any appropriate $s$ and $t$ (and, while this is implied by the previous relation, $f_0 = \operatorname{id}$).  A dynamical system indexed by the integers is a *discrete dynamical system*, while a system indexed by the reals is a *continuous dynamical system*.

Discrete dynamical systems can be thought of as iterative processes.  For example, [Newton's method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html) can be thought of as a discrete dynamical system:  suppose that $u : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuously differentiable function and that we want to find some value $x$ such that $u(x) = 0$.  Fix some initial guess, say $x_0$.  Then recursively define
$$ x_{n+1} := x_n - \frac{u(x_n)}{u'(x_n)}. $$
It is known that for almost every initial value $x_0$, there will be some $x_{\infty}$ such that $x_n \to x_{\infty}$ and $u(x_\infty) = 0.$  To understand this as a discrete time dynamical system, define the map
$$ f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} : x \mapsto x - \frac{u(x)}{u'(x)}. $$
This function $f$ "generates" a discrete time dynamical system, where $f_t$ is the $t$-iterate, i.e.
$$ f_t := f^t = \underbrace{f\circ f \circ \dotsb \circ f}_{\text{$t$ times}}, $$
where $t$ is a (nonnegative) integer.

#### Newton's Method as a Dynamical System

Recall that the motivation behind Newton's method is finding the zeros of functions.  We know that for almost any initial value, this dynamical system will be attracted to some zero (that is, the iterates will converge to a zero), but if a function has multiple zeros, it is not obvious *which* zero a sequence of iterates will limit towards.  For example, consider the polynomial function
$$ u(x) = x^3 + 1. $$
This function has *three* zeros in $\mathbb{C}$:  $x = -1$ and $x = \mathrm{e}^{\pm i\pi / 3}$.  Given an initial point $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, which of these three roots will be the limit of the dynamical system, applied to that point?  Thinking backwards, what is the set of points which are "attracted to" each of the three roots?  This set of points is the *basin of attraction*.  More formally:

> *Definition:* Let $\{f_t\}$ be a dynamical system, and suppose that $x^*$ is a point such that $f_t(x^*) = x^*$ for all $t$ (that is, suppose that $x^*$ is a *fixed point* of the system).  The *basin of attraction* of $x^*$ is the set of points
> $$ \left\{ x \ \middle|\ \lim_{t\to\infty} f_t(x) = x^* \right\}. $$

I bring up the example of Newton's method because I have [spilled some ink on that topic previously in my life](http://yozh.org/2012/10/02/newton_fractals/), and because it is an example that should be familiar to most people who have taken an introductory course in calculus.  However, the same framework can be used to describe the "hill climbing method" as a dynamical system.

#### Hill Climbing as a Dynamical System

When thinking of the hill climbing method as a dynamical system, we would like to say that the system is composed of iterates of the "hill climbing map" (i.e. a single step in the algorithm), and the fixed points are (local) optima.  If $x^*$ is some kind of maximum, then the set of points which are "reached" by the hill climbing algorithm is, in the language developed above, the basin of attraction of that maximum.

While this language is not entirely consistent with the theory of dynamical systems outlined above (since the step-size decreases with $t$, we are likely to lose the property $f_s \circ f_t = f_{s+t}$), we might think of the hill climbing method as a kind of "nonautonomous" dynamical system.  The same basic theory and vocabulary applies.

In short, it is entirely reasonable to refer to the set of points whose iterates (under the hill climbing function) limit to a particular value the *basin of attraction* of that value.

Comment: Excellent! (Finally I got time to read your post.) I have an couple of open question: 1) Is $e^{±\pi/3}`$ really a zero crossing for $x^3+1$ or did you make a typo? 2) Newton's method is known for "jumping" over zero crossing and reaching a far distant zero crossing. That is why it is used in the context of line search, where we calculate a step size. However - depending on how we implement the step size we might get different basins of attractions according to your definition. E.g. if we compare different constant step sizes, we might get different results. How to adapt your explanation?

Comment: @Make42 (1)  No, it should be $\mathrm{e}^{\pm i\pi/3}$.  I forgot the $i$.  (2) Newton's method does not have a "step size".  Yes, if the derivative is close to zero at a point, the subsequent iterate can be far away, but this is an intrinsic property of the function.  The basins of attraction for a given function do not vary.  Unless you are asking about the hill climbing algorithm?  In that case, the step size becomes a parameter of the dynamical system being described.  Different parameters may potentially give different basins.

Comment: Jorge (http://apmath.spbu.ru/cnsa/pdf/monograf/Numerical_Optimization2006.pdf, page 23) writes that $\alpha=1$ (step size) is the "natural step size" but it might need adapting. In any case: My point is this: I want to define the basin of attraction such, that no matter what the implementation uses as the local search optimization technique, it is clear what area I mean. In other words, I require a optimization method independent definition of the basin of attraction. I want to define the basin of attraction for a step size $\rightarrow 0$. If possible the definition should be short.

Comment: In the end I want to define a cluster for mean shift clustering and similar methods, but algorithm-free. I'll give my current definition of such a cluster above. It is pretty "bulky" - I would like to have a more elegant one. If possible even not for Euclidean, but for metric space.

Comment: @Make42 Regarding the cited file: note that the version of Newton's method I describe is for one variable. The paper seems to be describing implementations in higher dimensions, which may depend on a parameter (numerical analysis is not my area of expertise, so I can't say much more than that). In any event, I don't think that you are likely to be able to come up with an implementation independent notion of the basin of attraction. Indeed, $x\mapsto tan(x)-x$ and $x\mapsto \sin(x)-x\cos(x)$ have the same zeroes, but *very* different basins of attraction with respect to Newton's method.

Comment: @XanderHenerson: There might be a misunderstanding: When I say implementation independent, I am not talking about different functions (in your case $tan(x)-x$ vs $sin(x)-x\cdot cos(x)$). Obviously different functions would have different basins of attraction. Instead I am talking about using Newton's method vs using Hill Climbing or utilizing different parameters. In fact, I think that for $\mathbb R^n$ I did give a definition (see question). Albeit, I think it is not yet too elegant and I would like it to be valid for any general metric space as well.

Comment: @Make42 My point is that a different implementation *is* a different function.  I do not expect there to be any kind of implementation independent notion of a basin of attraction.

Comment: Ah, I now I see what you mean. Yeah, I wanted it to be dependent on $u$ but independent on $f$. Yes, I see that it *is* dependent on $f$, however I wanted a way to express the notion I described in the question. This *is* independent of $f$ - I am not using a time descrete dynamic system the way you did (as far as I understand). I am looking for an improvement of the definition. I am not bend on using a dynamic system.

Comment: That said, one might be able to use a local search (which is a dynamic system as you showed) with an infinitesimal neighborhood (step size) in the definition to describe what I want.